# SQL Subquery using Union mixing up results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find out which dealer has the most blue cars. The table schema is below:

`AVAILABLE_AUTO(SERIAL_NO,MODEL,COLOR,DEALER)`

I have the following query that returns the following results:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, DEALER
FROM global.AVAILABLE_AUTO
WHERE COLOR = "blue" AND DEALER = "DEALER ONE"
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, DEALER
FROM global.AVAILABLE_AUTO
WHERE COLOR = "blue" AND DEALER = "DEALER TWO";
```

```
|COUNT|DEALER    |
|----------------|
|1    |DEALER ONE|
|2    |DEALER TWO|
```

I am trying to select the Max of these two results, so I use the following query:

```sql
SELECT MAX(COUNT) AS COUNT, DEALER FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, DEALER
FROM global.AVAILABLE_AUTO
WHERE COLOR = "blue" AND DEALER = "DEALER ONE"
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, DEALER
FROM global.AVAILABLE_AUTO
WHERE COLOR = "blue" AND DEALER = "DEALER TWO"
) AS T1;
```

But it produces incorrect results:

```
|COUNT|DEALER    |
|----------------|
|2    |DEALER ONE|
```

`Dealer` in this case should be `DEALER TWO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a single query with `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, DEALER
FROM global.AVAILABLE_AUTO
WHERE COLOR = 'blue' AND DEALER IN ('DEALER ONE', 'DEALER TWO')
GROUP BY DEALER
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Your final query is malformed because `DEALER` is not in the `GROUP BY` but is in the `SELECT`.